# Apple encrypted DMG volumes strength?

Tags: aes

Apple OS X can create encrypted AES 128/256 DMG volumes. [Here](https://www.whitehatsec.com/blog/cracking-aes-256-dmgs-and-epic-self-pwnage/) is written about a men who was able to hack it. And also that DMGs use PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA-1. I couldn't find more information about encrypted DMGs. So does that mean that apples encrypted DMGs could be hacked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would have posted this as a comment if I could:
Please re-read the entire article that you have linked to.
All that was done was a brute force attack.

The reason brute force was possible was because the missing password was narrowed down to "about 22472" different possibilities.
And that 22000 was tried by a computer dedicated to doing such calculations.

This shows nothing about the security of the encryption scheme, only that when you know almost all of a password and have the means to try all possibilities efficiently, you can brute force it successfully.